# Fade out Two different divs at once with Jquery, then fade two more

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fade

What I'm wanting to do is fade out two different divs, and then fade in two other different divs. A friend told/shown me how to do this, but I've forgotten. Something about separating your divs with commas? It's not working, so I may be doing something wrong. Help would be appreciated.

```
$('#forward').click(function(){    
$('.contentRight', '.contentLeft').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('.contentRight2, .contentLeft2').fadeIn('slow');
});
});

$('#back').click(function(){    
$('.contentRight2', '.contentLeft2').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('.contentRight, .contentLeft').fadeIn('slow');
});
});
```

Comment: Post your HTML. And have you checked the console for errors?

Answer (score 2):

You're using the commas at the wrong place when specifying the selectors, so...

replace this:

```
$('.contentRight', '.contentLeft')...
```

with this:

```
$('.contentRight, .contentLeft')...
```

Comment: Fixed! Thank you, knew it was something to do with the commas.

Comment: thanks for the upvote, though you might as well want to select mine as the correct answer...? ;) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When fading out you have:

```
$('.contentRight', '.contentLeft').fadeOut(...
                 ^
```

When fading in you have:

```
$('.contentRight2, .contentLeft2').fadeIn(...
                 ^
```

Could it be because you are using separate quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Keep one quote around all comma separated values such as
$("#Abc,.zyz").fadeIn();

In both of your click functio  after click function krep these two divs into o e quote like mentioned above in examplr for abc and xyz

I am using nexus to give you this answer so cant tupe your example again.sorry for that comment here for further discussion if it doesny solve ur problem